# Creating nested messages in OpenPGP

Tags: encryption, public-key, pgp

I need to create a nested message in OpenPGP (my understanding is that the protocol itself should support it).

Let's say I have `Payload` ("Time in Lordran is convoluted").

I do the usual PGP encryption routine with a public key `PK1`, and as a result I get encrypted session key `SK1` and encrypted payload `EncPY1`. I can combine this output `OUT1` as a single PGP message.

Now, I want to do the same thing again: encrypt `OUT1` but with public key `PK2` to get `OUT2`. The problem here is that `OUT1` is going to generate a `Literal` data packet instead of `Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet`.

It means that to retrieve the `Payload`, the decryption of `OUT2` by GnuPG will happen in two passes (`gpg -d OUT2.gpg | gpg -d`) instead of one (`gpg -d OUT2.gpg`).

Excerpt from the RFC that confirms theoretical possibility:

```
   The Symmetrically Encrypted Data packet contains data encrypted with
   a symmetric-key algorithm.  When it has been decrypted, it contains
   other packets (usually a literal data packet or compressed data
   packet, but in theory other Symmetrically Encrypted Data packets or
   sequences of packets that form whole OpenPGP messages).
```

I have tried OpenPGP implementation in Go and there is no API to facilitate what I need. I would like to know if there is a library in Java, Python or any other language that fits my use case.

So far I haven't seen anyone in the libraries that I looked at that has tested creation of nested messages (except for compression).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All you have to do is to use Bouncy Castle Java library. All other libraries are absolute garbage.

None of the libraries have docs, but at least this one is not a binding to a thirty-year-old C code.

Comment: Moderator note: please tone it down a notch and reserve your strongest adjectives for much worse code, which does exist (trust me on that one). Also, have you reviewed all libraries?